# How to start Eclipse IDE in headless mode?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, headless

Can we start eclipse in headless mode without creating custom application and using that application as an argument to start the eclipse in headless mode.

`eclipsec -application test.customapplication`

Here `test.customapplication` is an Application which implements the IApplication.

Without creating custom application can we use any inbuilt eclipse applications to start the eclipse in the headless mode ?

Here i am looking for exact existing application that can be used to start the eclipse in the headless mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no mechanism for this.

You **must** create a custom application implementing `IApplication`.

Comment: I have my custom application and i am not starting the workbench instead importing and building the projects. My problem is some of the required plugins are not loaded to the platform in this case.

Comment: Well if you don't start the workbench some things (such as UI code) are not available. Ask a new question explaining exactly what you want and what is missing.